# SonarQube 5 Service account permissions

Tags: elasticsearch, sonarqube, sonarqube5.6

We are currently running SonarQube 5.2 and are performing a test upgrade to SonarQube 5.6, we have had this issue with Sonar 5.4 as well, but never upgraded in production.

When we use the same service account on the same server in the same root directory, the service is unable to start. It claims it is unable to get a node lock, always on the same file and directory, node 49, which is the last one of the nodes. The file and folder are successfully created.

The service account has full permissions on the D:\Sonar folder and all folders below.

I have tested and confirmed that the service does start up when i make it a local administrator, but this is not desired, so i am looking for the required permissions to start up the service. The service also starts if i configure it as local system, but we dont want this either.

What more permissions should i give to the SonarQube Service Account in order to start up ?

Any advise is welcome.

Nico

```
2016.06.10 14:42:32 INFO  app[o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory D:\Sonar\sonarqube-5.6\temp
2016.06.10 14:42:32 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[es]: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\Sonar\sonarqube-5.6\temp -javaagent:C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\lib\management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer D:\Sonar\sonarqube-5.6\temp\sq-process3739686975987017449properties
2016.06.10 14:42:34 INFO   es[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint]  Starting es
2016.06.10 14:42:34 INFO   es[o.s.s.EsSettings]  Elasticsearch listening on 127.0.0.1:9006
2016.06.10 14:42:34 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1465562551839] version[1.7.5], pid[29336], build[00f95f4/2016-02-02T09:55:30Z]
2016.06.10 14:42:34 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1465562551839] initializing ...
2016.06.10 14:42:34 INFO   es[o.e.plugins]  [sonar-1465562551839] loaded [], sites []
2016.06.10 14:42:35 WARN   es[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint]  Fail to start es
org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchIllegalStateException: Failed to obtain node lock, is the following location writable?: [D:\Sonar\sonarqube-5.6\data\es\sonarqube]
    at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.<init>(NodeEnvironment.java:164) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.internal.InternalNode.<init>(InternalNode.java:165) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.search.SearchServer.start(SearchServer.java:45) [sonar-search-5.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:102) ~[sonar-process-5.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.search.SearchServer.main(SearchServer.java:81) [sonar-search-5.6.jar:na]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: failed to obtain lock on D:\Sonar\sonarqube-5.6\data\es\sonarqube\nodes\49
    at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.<init>(NodeEnvironment.java:151) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
    ... 4 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: D:\Sonar\sonarqube-5.6\data\es\sonarqube\nodes\49
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileStore.create(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.getFileStore(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.nio.file.Files.getFileStore(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.getFileStore(NodeEnvironment.java:262) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.access$000(NodeEnvironment.java:62) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment$NodePath.<init>(NodeEnvironment.java:75) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.<init>(NodeEnvironment.java:140) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
    ... 4 common frames omitted
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Comment: Are you able to fix this issue? I am looking for the same ?

Comment: its been a while ago, but i believe i ended up running the instance as the local system account, that did work.

Comment: I was able to run it with Service Account, with below permissions: 1) Run as Logon Service 2) I put the service account to Local Administrator Account and now it is working fine with Integrated security with MS SQL Server as back end database.

Answer (score 0):

In order to run with service account you need below permissions:

•   Logon as a service via GPO
•   Local Admin permission on server

Also make sure you have permissions for the service account on the Database in order to make it work properly.

[Also posted on Site](https://scientistz.com/2020/06/03/solved-sonarqube-service-account-permissions-in-windows/)